# Remove element from nested object

Tags: javascript, object

I have following object:

```
{"2":{"cid":"2","uid":"2"},"1":{"cid":"1","uid":"3"}}
```

In this example I want to remove

```
"1":{"cid":"1","uid":"3"}
```

from it.
I have tried all solutions that I found on Stack Overflow, and could not make any of them work. I am mostly PHP person, so I might miss something important here?

Comment: This is not an array it's an `Object`.

Comment: To get an array you should use `[]` not `{}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove a key from a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455405/how-to-remove-a-key-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: there are no arrays in this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use `delete` with the appropriate property.

```
var obj = {"2":{"cid":"2","uid":"2"},"1":{"cid":"1","uid":"3"}};

delete obj["1"];
```

Note the `"` around the 1 to mark it as an identifier and not as an array index!

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the comment, `obj` is an object and no array no matter how you address the  `[1]` property. My last note was just to make it clear that you are working with an object and not an array.

In my experience most people associate integer properties with arrays and string properties with objects. So I thought it might be more helpful to highlight the property in the way given.

Comment: It's not an array index because *obj* is an object, not because the value is a string. An early step in resolving property names is to convert them to strings, so the outcome of `obj[1]` and `obj['1']` are indistinguishable in the same way `obj[(function(){return 1;}())]` would be. And since Arrays are Objects, `array[1]` is identical in outcome to `array['1']`.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var myObj= {"2":{"cid":"2","uid":"2"},"1":{"cid":"1","uid":"3"}}

delete myObj['1'];

alert ( myObj['1']);
```

please notice there are Cross platform problems with delete :

Cross-browser issues

> Although ECMAScript makes iteration order of objects
>   implementation-dependent, it may appear that all major browsers
>   support an iteration order based on the earliest added property coming
>   first (at least for properties not on the prototype). However, in the
>   case of Internet Explorer, when one uses delete on a property, some
>   confusing behavior results, preventing other browsers from using
>   simple objects like object literals as ordered associative arrays. In
>   Explorer, while the property value is indeed set to undefined, if one
>   later adds back a property with the same name, the property will be
>   iterated in its old position--not at the end of the iteration sequence
>   as one might expect after having deleted the property and then added
>   it back.

Comment: using dot notation on numeric indices gives syntax errors, use brackets!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ive already corrected it while you were writing this msg

Comment: It looks like you're quoting MDN. Probably a good idea to credit the source. :)

Comment: @amnotiam Ive  put it in quote tags ...and it takes 1 seconds to search it in the web to get to mdn....

Comment: @amnotiam I dont wanna be a child , but i saw cpule of your answers which had a quotes without any link or credit.... but i wont post them. we (including you) dont have to be "sharp right " all the time....

Comment: If that's the case, I would *appreciate* it if someone gave me a reminder. It baffles me that you would be so apparently offended by a friendly reminder.

Comment: @amnotiam I really appreciate you suggestion.... you gave me some good answers back then in jQuery....:)

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr=[[10,20,30],[40,50,60],[70,80,90]];

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
        if(arr[i][j]==50){
            arr[i].splice(j,1);
        }
    }
}

document.write(arr);
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have multi dimensional Arrays, only arrays and objects. That said: `delete theObject['1'];` should work just fine

Comment: javascript does have multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @jbabey: granted, if all keys are numeric the var will behave as an array, but in this example: if you assign values step by step (`var theArray = []; theArray['1'] = []; theArray['1']['cid']='2';`), try doing something like `theArray['1'].length`, or try `theArray.length`. These methods return `0` and `2` respectively. It's best to approach the var as an object.

Comment: i realize the OP is not using arrays, but that does not mean that javascript multi-dimensional arrays cease to exist :P

Comment: fair enough :)... just read your comment under the question itself. It's just one of those common misconceptions, questions starting with 'I have this multi-dimensional Array' followed by an object... it's just something that gets on my nerves, but than I guess I am a bit pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use delete in javascript
Ex:

```
var x = {"2":{"cid":"2","uid":"2"},"1":{"cid":"1","uid":"3"}};

delete x['1'];
```

Also, check this:

> [Deleting Objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Assign your `Object` (not an `Array`) to a variable, this way:

```
var o = {"2":{"cid":"2","uid":"2"},"1":{"cid":"1","uid":"3"}};
```

Then do:

```
delete o['1'];
```

That's it!