# Removing an element from a multi-dimensional Array jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

How do I remove an item from the orange frame?

[image: obrazek]

I tried

```
product.splice(product[0]["elements"][0], 1);
```

But not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element from multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174750/remove-element-from-multidimensional-array)

Comment: write your expected output and your current result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove element by using `delete`:

```
delete product[0]["elements"][0];
```