# Remove value from an Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have code like below. I would like to remove `verse` from `verses` object.

```
_self.verses.filter(verse => {
    Object.keys(verse).forEach(function(key) {
       if(! _self.recieved_translation.includes(key))
       {
         // I would like to remove this verse from verses                       
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: `delete verses[key];`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455405/how-do-i-remove-a-key-from-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_self.verses.filter(verse => {
    Object.keys(verse).forEach(function(key) {
       if(! _self.recieved_translation.includes(key))
       {
              delete verses[verses];                  
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `delete` to remove items from obj

Answer (score 0):

```
_self.verses.forEach(verse => delete verse.verse);
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` skips elements, for which its callback returns `false`. Just see if you have the problematic key and return according boolean.

```
_self.verses = _self.verses.filter(verse => {
    // We don't need foreach here, we just need the first key
    var keyWithoutTranslation = Object.keys(verse).find(function(key) {
       return !_self.recieved_translation.includes(key);
    });
    // Now the filter will do the rest
    return keyWithoutTranslation === undefined;
});
```