# Alternative to lodash omit

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I would like to delete a property and return a new object without mutating the original object.

I know we can do this easily with Lodash like this:

```js
const profile = { name: 'Maria', age: 30 }
_.omit(profile, name) // it returns a new object without the property name {age: 30}
```

However, I would like to know if it's possible to do it with vanilla JavaScript without assigning that value to `undefined` or using a `filter`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a key from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455405/how-do-i-remove-a-key-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Thank so much you but as I said I don't want to change the current object, neither use `undefined`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For a single key you can [destructure the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), and use [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) with [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to create an object without the property:

```js
const omitSingle = (key, { [key]: _, ...obj }) => obj
const profile = { name: 'Maria', age: 30 }

const result = omitSingle('name', profile)

console.log(result)
```

To omit multiple properties, you can convert the object to [key, value] pairs, filter the pairs according to the listed keys array, and then convert back to an object via `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const omit = (keys, obj) => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .filter(([k]) => !keys.includes(k))
  )
  
const profile = { name: 'Maria', gender: 'Female', age: 30 }

const result = omit(['name', 'gender'], profile)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much your first option was exactly what I was looking for, a perfect vanilla alternative to `_.omit` even though that syntax is totally new for me.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added some links that might give you more info.

Answer (score 10):

```
 const obj = { 
   prop0: 0, 
   prop1: 1, 
   prop2: 2, 
   prop3: 3, 
 };
   
 const prunedObj = (({ prop1, prop2, ...rest }) => rest)(obj);

 // prunedObj => { prop0: 0, prop3: 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this.

```js
export const flattenKeys = (s) =>
  s
    .replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1')
    .replace(/^\./, '')
    .split('.');

export const omit = (object, path) => {
  const obj = object;

  let keys = path;

  if (typeof keys === 'string') {
    keys = flattenKeys(keys);
  }

  if (keys.length === 1) {
    delete obj[keys];

    return undefined;
  }

  return omit(obj[keys[0]], keys.slice(1).join('.'));
};
```

Example:

```js
const data = {
  user: {
    name: 'Khoa',
    age: 24
  },
  company: {
    name: 'Test',
  }
}

omit(data, 'company.name')

// output:
// { user: { name: 'Khoa', age: 24 }, company: {} }
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far which deals with nested object. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a nested object, try to clone as follows:

```js
const profile = { name: 'Maria', age: 30 }

function deleteProperty(object, property){
  var clonedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
  delete clonedObject[property];
  return clonedObject;
}

var newProfile = deleteProperty(profile, "name");

console.log(profile);
console.log(newProfile);
```

Comment: Thank so much that's a easy and straightforward solution, I really like it

Comment: What's the advantage of using JSON.parse over the spread operator like so: const clonedObject = {...object} ?

Comment: The spread operator is not supported as widely (e.g. IE11). That said, serializing/deserializing to JSON has some overhead so I would prefer the spread operator if possible!

Answer (score 0):

wrote a package just to solve this issue

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fp-omit

it doesn't mutate or uses `delete` under the hood, but pure functional [rambda](https://ramdajs.com/) function

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation of the accepted answer that just uses rest params:

```js
const omit = (o, ...paths) => 
 Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(([k]) => !paths.includes(k)))
```