# Remove specfic key in JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ecmascript-6

I am having an JSON object looks like this

```
{
value: {
  "0": {
    dummy: "dummy1",
    data : "One",
  },
},
value2: {
  "0": {
    dummy: "dummy2",
    data : "two",
  },
},
value3: {
  "0": {
    dummy: "dummy3",
    data : "three",
  },
}
```

}

I want output like this

```
{
value: {
  "0": {
    data : "One",
  },
},
value2: {
  "0": {
    data : "two",
  },
},
value3: {
  "0": {
    data : "three",
  },
}
```

}

I am able to traverse the root element of all the objects but not able to traverse the array, tried using map but nothing helped.

Comment: There isn't any JSON in your question. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure (usually an object or an array). What you posted in the question is the data structure (a JavaScript array), not its JSON representation.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3455416/5867572 - the `delete operator` allows this.

**Seriously - one search found the answer in less than a minute. I have included it because I didn't know about the delete operator and assume others might be interested, but the idea of SO is to answer questions that have had at least a modicum of research.**

Also - if I was doing this - I would find a better way than simply repeating the delete operator 3 times - but that needs to be more thought out in the data structure.

Note that

```js
let origData = {
  "value": {
  "1": {
    dummy: "dummy1",
    data : "One"
   }
  },
  "value2": {
    "0": {
      dummy: "dummy2",
      data : "two"
    }
  },
  "value3": {
    "0": {
      dummy: "dummy3",
      data : "three"
    }
  }
}


 delete origData["value"]["1"]["dummy"];
 delete origData["value2"]["0"]["dummy"];
 ddelete origData["value3"]["0"]["dummy"];

 console.log(origData); // logs the original object without the deleted keys / properties
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do that dynamically traversing all the objects and removing the keys? Thanks  in advance

Comment: yes - but you need to structure the data to support it - look at the data you have - a random collection of  keys with variable numbers on them - organise these better then you can simply perform a loop and use the insdex to identify the key you want to delete. But you have to work that out on your own - otherwise you will never learn how to structure your datafor the functionality you are trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative, dynamic solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = {
  value: { 0: { dummy: 'dummy1', data: 'One' } },
  value2: { 0: { dummy: 'dummy2', data: 'two' } },
  value3: { 0: { dummy: 'dummy3', data: 'three' } }
};

const prune = objectScan(['*.0.data'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ parent, property }) => {
    delete parent[property];
  }
});

console.log(prune(data));
// => 3

console.log(data);
/* => {
  value: { '0': { dummy: 'dummy1' } },
  value2: { '0': { dummy: 'dummy2' } },
  value3: { '0': { dummy: 'dummy3' } }
} */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.3.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)