# How to remove key value pair from an object having values as another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, javascript-objects

Here I have created a data based on my backend get call response. So I came across usecase where my data have to match with my backend data type.

The data I have generated looks like this:

```
var valGroup = {
    "Tier1": [
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0,
            "category": "Tier1"
        },
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0.8,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0,
            "category": "Tier1"
        }
    ],
    "Tier2": [
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0,
            "category": "Tier2"
        },
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0,
            "category": "Tier2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here from the above mentioned data I have to remove the "category" key value pair like this:

```
var valGroup = {
    "Tier1": [
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0
        },
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0.8,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0
        }
    ],
    "Tier2": [
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0
        },
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried something with Object.keys and going through my object's key and index but can't delete that key/value pair. Is there any other approach by which I can get the required data?

Comment: Please show your exact attempt and the actual result. Was there an error in the console?

Comment: var data = Object.keys(valGroup).forEach(async function(key, index) {
      await console.log(key,valGroup[key],"OE",fullData);
    });

valGroup[key] returns every main object's value, that is array of objects 
From valGroup[key] I tried to filter the category and delete it. But it's throwing undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you tried that with `object.keys()` ... here is a solution how that would look like:

```js
var valGroup = {
    "Tier1": [
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0,
            "category": "Tier1"
        },
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0.8,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0,
            "category": "Tier1"
        }
    ],
    "Tier2": [
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "0",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0,
            "category": "Tier2"
        },
        {
            "DE": 0,
            "CreditRange": "",
            "VintageCriteria": [],
            "DBR": 0,
            "NetsalesCriteria": [],
            "ABBmultiplier": 0,
            "BTO": 0,
            "MUE": [],
            "TurnoverCriteria": 0,
            "DSCR": 0,
            "category": "Tier2"
        }
    ]
}

const result = Object.fromEntries([
    ...Object.keys(valGroup)
        .map(key => [key, valGroup[key].map(({category, ...rest}) => rest)])
])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works fine on my local. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a line that shows how it could be done:

```
Object.keys(valGroup).forEach(key => valGroup[key].forEach(arrayElement => delete arrayElement['category']))
```

You can use it to create a function or whatever you'd prefer.
Here is another thread that shows more examples: [How do I remove a key from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455405/how-do-i-remove-a-key-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I have tried this now in my local system, it's showing undefined error on console.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lv197fw2/

Comment: You missed to iterate through the array of objects so I acceped the below answer whick works for me.