# Convert an object to an interface with less keys in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have this interface

```
interface Product {
    id: string
    name: string
  }
```

and the one that extends it

```
interface AdminProduct extends Product {
    isVisible: boolean
  }
```

then i have this code

```
  const adminProducts = (await queryByCollection('product')) as AdminProduct[]

  const products = adminProducts.filter((product) => {
    if (!product.isVisible) {
      return
    }
  }).map((product)=> product as Product) as Product[]

  return products
```

even though i define the return type of product when i map adminProducts array it still has the key 'isVisible' in it

how to convert an object to smaller interface and delete all redundant keys?

Comment: Force assigning a type doesn't mutate an object, it just indicates to TS that it should treat the value *as if* it were that type. In your case TS does adhere to the new type —  `products[0].isVisible` will error as expected even though the object might actually have that property. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAd3kN)

Comment: i see, but i there a way to actualy mutate an object?

Comment: Sure, [How do I remove a key from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455405/how-do-i-remove-a-key-from-a-javascript-object). Or you could `map` after your filter `.map(({isVisible, ...product})=> product)`

Comment: But your `filter()` call actually doesn't make sense. Filter expects a boolean as return, so to filter only products that aren't visible you would simply `.filter((product) => !product.isVisible)`

Comment: Yes, but i thought there was a way to someshow automate this process. I wonder if it can detect redundant keys by itself and delete them.

Comment: No, you'll need to implement that yourself.

Comment: ok, that thing with 'map' looks good, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript only presents in build time and after transpile, `tsc` (typescript compiler) will remove all typescript types and only javascript remains.
So can't expect to manipulate the data by TS.
You have to do it in the javascript area:

```
adminProducts
   .filter((adminProduct) => adminProducts.isVisible)
   .map(({isVisible, ...product}) => product)
```

With this code, you will remove `isVisible` from your list.